# Turning a matlab string with a numbers and colon to an array populated using colon

Tags: arrays, matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

If I have some string newStr = 1×1 cell array

```
{'1 25 27 45 46 62 65 70 73 76 77:83'}
```

Is there any way to directly convert this to an array?

```
my_array = [1 25 27 45 46 62 65 70 73 76 77:83];
```

which would result in

```
my_array =

 1    25    27    45    46    62    65    70    73    76    77    78    79    80    81    82    83
```

Comment: Yes, using `eval` : `eval(['[', newStr{1}, ']' ])` . But using it may imply that the defining or storage of the data could be done better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `str2num`

```
a = {'1 25 27 45 46 62 65 70 73 76 77:83'}
my_array = str2num(a{1})

my_array =

  Columns 1 through 12

     1    25    27    45    46    62    65    70    73    76    77    78

  Columns 13 through 17

    79    80    81    82    83
```

Comment: Note that `str2num` uses `eval` under the hood which is why the above works, but this also makes this a security vulnerability if someone evil can modify the content of the string (for instance, by the string coming from standard input).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which completely avoid the use of `eval`. It is not as elegant as a one liner but it doesn't expose you to the risks of `eval`. If someone try to inject malicious code in the input string, the worst it will do is error, not execute rogue code.

In your example, there is only one `colon assignment` instruction, located at the end. I made my solution more generic assuming these instructions can be multiple and randomly placed. So for example I considered the following input string:

```
a = {'1 25 27 45 46 62 65 70 73 76 77:83 99 101:105'}
```

With this as a starting point, run the following:

```
%% 
fullArray    = strsplit(a{1},' ') ;         % split the string into a cell array
scalarArray  = str2double(fullArray) ;      % convert all simple scalar values
idxNotScalar = find(isnan(scalarArray)) ;   % find cells with "colon" operator

% split the arrays
colonArray  = fullArray(idxNotScalar) ;     % place colon instruction in a separate array
scalarArray(idxNotScalar) = [] ;            % clear them from the scalarArray

%% Now parse the colon instructions cells
nElem = numel(colonArray) ;
ctmp  = cell(nElem,1) ;
for k=1:nElem
    c = textscan( colonArray{k} , '%d:%d' ) ;
    ctmp{k,1} = double( c{1}:c{2} ) ;
end

%% now concatenate all results and sort
my_array = sort(cat(2,scalarArray,ctmp{:})) ;
```

To obtain:

```
my_array =
     1    25    27    45    46    62    65    70    73    76    77    78    79    80    81    82    83    99   101   102   103   104   105
```